# Mobile upload email for a Facebook app page

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-pages

How can I get a mobile upload email address for a Facebook app page I created?

By visiting the [Facebook Mobile](http://www.facebook.com/mobile) section of the site I only get one for my private Facebook profile.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem this is possible, you reach a "road block" when going to the url as a Facebook Page (instead of a user), with the following message,

> You are using Facebook as [Name of Facebook Page]
>   To access this page, you'll need to
>   switch from using Facebook as your
>   page to using Facebook as yourself.